# React Native container/presentation components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I want to know how to properly use container/presentation components together in my app. Here's my current approach which may or may not work properly:

```
export default class AppEntry extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <NotificationContainer>
                    <LocationContainer>
                        <ModalBoxContainer>
                           <App />
                        </ModalBoxContainer>
                    </LocationContainer>
                </NotificationContainer>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

This approach does not seem right to me. But so far it does work. Is there a way to combine all of my containers into one without them all being in one file? Each container is currently a class in its own file. The  tag is where all of my navigation, screens and components are.

What I'm trying to accomplish is for my location, notification, modal box ect. classes to work globally anywhere in the application. An Example is that my notification container has event listeners that need to be working while the user is in any screen of the application. That is why I have a container for the notification class wrapped around the  tag. Correct me if this assumption is incorrect.

Is there something that I am not understanding about how to accomplish this in app development?

Thanks in advance. Hoping to learn something valuable from this.